# Objective c - Weird behavior with int

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an object that stores a property as an int.

When in the console I type `po menuItem.quantity` I get a `1` which is what I'm expecting.

If I try to use that to populate a label with this line of code:

```
label_Quantity.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", menuItem.quantity];
```

I instead get a `414280896`

Also, please have a look at the following image:

[image]

For some reason it says `_quantity = (int) 414280896`but when I click on the `i` icon, I get a `1`.

What is going on here?

EDIT 1:

Per a commenter's request, this is MenuItemDTO:

```
@interface MenuItemDTO : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int menuItemID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* description;
@property (nonatomic) int quantity;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* imageURL;
@property (nonatomic) int categoryID;
@property (nonatomic) float price;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isSponsoredItem;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate* lastModifiedDate;

@end
```

And it got created like this:

```
MenuItemDTO * menuItem = [MenuItemDTO new];
menuItem.quantity = [Converter fromDictionaryValueToInt:[json objectForKey:@"Quantity"]];
```

json is an NSDictionary with different values coming from a web service.

`Converter fromDictionaryValueToInt` looks like this:

```
+ (int)fromDictionaryValueToInt:(NSNumber *)value
{
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        return 0;

    return [value intValue];
}
```

EDIT 2:

I found the problem, but don't understand why it didn't work.
The problem didn't come when initializing. That was working just fine. It looks like later in the code, quantity was being assigned another value like this:

```
menuItem.quantity = (int)[dict objectForKey:@"Total"];
```

That was giving the problem with the weird number. Now I'm doing this:

```
menuItem.quantity = [Converter fromDictionaryValueToInt:[dict objectForKey:@"Total"]];
```

And it's working fine. If anyone can explain to me why the first method didn't work, I'll select that answer. Otherwise, I'll put this myself later and select mine.

Thanks to the commenters for helping me out.

Comment: I would guess a not initialized value but maybe I am wrong.
Can you show how you created your `menuItem` ;)

Comment: looks menuItemID have garbage value  set initial value to 0 while intializing the menuItemID.quantity = 0

Comment: first of all while debugging use p instead of po for primitive data types. And you need to check wether menuItem is initialized or not

Comment: @CladClad I just added more info per your request. Thanks

Comment: @Shubhendu mmm, when I use p I get a `(int) $8 = 414280896`. Why am I getting a 1 when using po, and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: MenuItemDTO * menuItem = [MenuItemDTO new];
menuItem.quantity = 0 ;
menuItem.quantity = [Converter fromDictionaryValueToInt:[json objectForKey:@"Quantity"]]; try and let me know

Comment: p is used for primitive datatypes so it shows you correct value. You just need to check whether menuItem is initialized or not and if initialized than check are you assigning quantity

Comment: Hey guys, please look at Edit 2. I fixed it, but don't know what was wrong. Can anyone explain? Thanks!

Comment: I think this question should be deleted as I cannot see it helping anyone.  You solved it by finding code you did not originally disclose and it's fairly obvious why this bug caused the things you saw within the debugger.

Comment: @trojanfoe perhaps it's fairly obvious to you, but it wasn't to me, and it could help someone like me. The answer that I chose gives a clear explanation of what happened and that is very helpful.

Comment: I did not vote the question down, in fact your question contains no down votes at all.  So it seems what's obvious to you, and what is not, is different to everyone else.

Comment: It did when I wrote it... As it had 2 and went down to 1 the momento you made that comment. That's why I assumed that. Sorry about that. I now deleted that part from the comment.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I did remove my upvote, which is why it went from 2 to 1 (note that is not the same as a downvote).  I removed my upvote for the reasons given in the comment; I believe this question won't help anyone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDictionnary`can only store NSObject, that means that when you call `[dict objectForKey:@"Total"]`it return a `NSNumber *` instead of an `int` and that's why your `fromDictionaryValueToInt` work.

If you write `menuItem.quantity = (int)[dict objectForKey:@"Total"];` the `(int)` cast say to the compiler: I want to convert this `NSNumber` pointer address into an `int` so `menuItem.quantity` will receive the address and not the value.